# How do I delete all my mail in Gmail for a mailbox I have disconnected?

Tags: gmail, google-account

So I deleted my **Gmail service** from my **Google account** from https://myaccount.google.com

Now my Google Account is linked only to a different email address I use.

However, in my Google Drive service, I still see Gmail takes around 14GB of space.

How can I delete the mail in that Gmail account? As I said, I already deleted the Gmail service itself.

Comment: Why is this question voted to be deleted?

Comment: You probably need to restore that Gmail account, delete the mail, then get rid of it again.

Comment: ...if that's even possible.